# Intent Service does not call onDestroy after Rescheduling & setIntentRedelivery is true

Tags: java, android, service, android-intentservice

I'm running Intent service on a button click. And I want Intent Service to restart if it crashes during its execution.

I have created an Intent Service and for it to restart automatically after crashing, I have setIntentRedelivery to true in service Constructor.

Here is my Intent Service

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final String TAG = "MyTag";

    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
        setIntentRedelivery(true);    
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent: called");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent: Counter is: "+(i+1));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: called");
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the intent service to call onDestroy after restarting. But thats not the case. Service is restarting with intent and onHandleIntent completes its task but does not call the onDestroy.
Note: If service is not crashed, it calls onDestroy, but if services crashes and is restarted after some, it completes the onHandleIntet task but does not calls the onDestroy.